# Help me find $S_{-2}$ using the polynomial

Tags: polynomials, roots

[image]

I found the equation , then I found $S_3$ :

$$S_3-S_1-3=0$$

And I found $S_3$

Also I gave it a try using  the Generalized form:

$$S_n+S_{n-2}+S_{n-3}=0$$

Let $n=0$

$$S_1+S_{-1}+S_{-2}=0$$

**Now I can't find $S_{-1}$ in order to find $S_{-2}$**

**How to find $S_{-2}$ ?** Any help  is much appreciated.

Comment: Did you notice that the product of the three roots of your second polynomial is $1$?

Comment: Does factorizing help? 8x3+12x2+4x-1=4x(2x+1)(x+1)-1 and y3-y-1=y(y+1)(y-1)-1